# Jest encountered an unexpected token: export { default as v1 } with uuid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, babeljs

I am writing the Jest test for my react component in Monorepo. However, I entercounted this error when I running the Jest test.

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /node_modules/.pnpm/uuid@8.3.2/node_modules/uuid/dist/esm-browser/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export { default as v1 } from './v1.js';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

I tried to add these to the `babel.config.js`, but it is still not working.

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}],
        '@babel/preset-typescript',
    ],
};
```

I hope the Jest test will execute normally without any compiling errors!

Comment: You still need help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, and adding `jest.mock` in the test files fixes the issue for me.
Here the block code which I added in the test files:

```
jest.mock('uuid', () => {
  return {
    v4: jest.fn(() => 1)
  }
})
```